# Command line parameters specified in NetBeans 8.2 turns up when running .jar from command line

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I have searched for a way to change this (unwanted) behavior.
I set command line arguments in Project->Properties->Run->Parameters and run my program in NetBeans IDE. Arguments gets passed to my program just fine, but they also turn up when I run the .jar from a .bat-file or .sh-script after it is compiled. 
So my customer ends up having my test arguments activated if I forget to remove the settings from project settings before distributing my .jar.
I would have expected this info to be removed from the .jar. At least after compiling without debug information.
Is there a way to remove the arguments from my distribution without removing them from my project settings? 
Anyone else having the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a configuration (Project->Properties->Configurations->Add), select the created configuration under "Project->Properties->Run" and specify the arguments only for this configuration.
But this way is NetBeans specific. If you are using Maven you should use profiles. Add something like this into your pom.xml:

```
<project>
   ...
   <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>test</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <!--your command line arguments-->
                <exec.args>hello world</exec.args>
            </properties>            
        </profile>
    </profiles>
   ...
</project>
```

You still would need to remember to deactivate your development profile before shipping but like this you can separate the configuration between development and production system in a clean way. (Especially if later on there should be other configuration values which should differ, like logging level, different paths and so on).